# Strange issue with glReadPixels

Tags: android, opengl-es

I´m having this strange issue when using a GL10-object outside of the overridden Renderer functions.

For example, for the purpose of picking a geometry via color codes I tried to read out the color buffer via glReadPixels.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

...

    ByteBuffer pixel = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
    pixel.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);

    while (pixel.hasRemaining()){
    Log.v(TAG,""+(int)(pixel.get() & 0xFF));
    }

}
```

This works and gives me the color values in range 0..255 for the pixel in the bottom left corner.
Now when I take my GL10-object and make it available to the whole class as a field, it doesn´t seem to work anymore:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
Log.v(TAG, "update Observer glsurfaceviewrenderer");
if (data instanceof MotionEvent){
    MotionEvent event = (MotionEvent) data;

    ByteBuffer pixel = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
    pixel.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);


    while (pixel.hasRemaining()){
    Log.v(TAG,""+(int)(pixel.get() & 0xFF));

    }

}
}
```

This doesn´t work, all colors have value 0. Only difference is, I used the gl-object via a field and not via a function-argument. I checked the memory pointer to the gl-object by printing it to Log and both have the same address.

I´m really stumped right now...anybody having an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1) You can only make OpenGL calls from the thread to which the context is bound. onDrawFrame runs in a thread created by GLSurfaceView, while I assume your update method is called from the main UI thread.

2) glReadPixels reads from the buffer you are currently rendering to. After onDrawFrame returns, GLSurfaceView will call eglSwapBuffers. You will no longer be able to read the buffer you were drawing to.

You'll need to reorganize your code so that you know what pixel you need to read at time that onDrawFrame is called. Your only other option is to fetch the entire frame every time.

Comment: from http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglSwapBuffers.html
The contents of the color buffer are left unchanged if the value of the EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR attribute of surface is EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED, and are undefined if the value is EGL_BUFFER_DESTROYED. Attribute EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR is supported only if the EGL version is 1.2 or greater.But Android supports only EGL10 and EGL11.
If the renderer is implemented in JNI you have to call eglSwapBuffers by yourself, so you can control more the behaviour of your rendering cycle. see native-activity sample in Android NDK.